# Parser or web crawler

Tags: php, html-parsing, web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to extract data from ehow.com regarding different topics to store in my database. Problem is there are multiple web pages I have to sift through to get the info from this website. In order to to go through the multitude of web pages and pull the data I need, would I use a scraper like SimpleHTMLDOM or would I need to use a web crawler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First consider that you're allowed to do that on eHow.com or not. I guess you couldn't do that in the way you explained here.

Anyways, regarding your question:

`Crawler` moves from page to page and/or website to website, and `Parser` will parse the page content and will store them in a reusable way which meet your needs. In order to do that, you need both of them, or you need to provide the URLs for your Parser manually.

**Update:**

Useful links about `Crawler`:

[PHP Crawler](http://astellar.com/php-crawler/)

[PHPCrawl](http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/)

[Simple PHP crawler example](http://webdevwonders.com/simple-php-crawler-example/)

Comment: I've updated my answer! About parser SimpleHTMLDOM is a good choice I think. :)

Answer (score 1):

A web crawler is just a wrapper around a parser (like SimpleHTMLDOM) for automatically fetching pages by following links.

Do you need to do that?

In either case, [the terms and conditions](http://www.ehow.com/terms-of-use.html) of eHow forbid using automated means to access the site.

Comment: Ok,lets say it was a website that would allow it. What do you mean by "Do I need to do that?" What would be the more efficient way? @Quentin

Comment: Do you need to automatically follow links or not? It isn't a question of efficiency, it is a question of what your requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

You could build your own crawler with relative ease...

In PHP you could use for example...

```
<?php

$lines = file('http://www.example.com/');

// i think here you either implode or explode the $lines by "" cannot remember which

// Loop through our array, show HTML source as HTML source; and line numbers too.
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    echo "Line #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />\n";
}

preg_match_all("/<h2>(.*)<\/h2>/i",$lines,$array_of_contents);

$page_title = $array_of_contents[0][1];

if($page_title == "Technology"){

// run a function here to do something with links found on this page...

}

?>
```

It would be better to use CURL instead of file(), though you may need to enable it in the PHP.ini. I have done this before on a different website and it works pretty well. When interesting to you links are found, add them to a database and keep crawling until you have found all the links you want, then use another class etc to proccess/scrape the data at the collected urls...